# Convert comma separated string to array without coded quotations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I have:

```
<%= "a,b,c".split(',') %>
```

this is what I get in view:

```
[&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;]
```

How can I achieve this:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Comment: This is due to your context rendering erb. `"a,b,c".split(',') #=> ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: I just guessed it was erb, but it might be anything else.

Comment: Why do you want `['a','b','c']` in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by,

```
<%= "a,b,c".split(',').inspect %>
```

or by

```
<%= "a,b,c".split(',').to_s.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Rails I'm going to guess that this is JSON.

The first step is to decode the HTML entities with `CGI.unescapeHTML`:

```
str = '[&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;]'
json = CGI.unescapeHTML(str)
# => "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Now decode the JSON:

```
JSON.parse(json)
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I think in Rails the CGI module is available by default, but if not you'll need to do `require "cgi"` first.